# UML - Class diagram and Activity Diagram

Tags: java, uml

This is my first time using stackoverflow so sorry for not formatting correctly.

My questions (Java):

1. If I have a private method that doesn't interact with the user at all (Example: A method that returns a string that helps another public method) do I need to show it in the Class Diagram?
2. If I have a method that I made runs automatically when a program starts do I have to put it into Activity Diagram?

Comment: 1] Generally speaking, no. Private methods aid implementation, so there is no reason for exposure. 2] Again, generally no. In most cases the activity diagram is reasonably high-level.

Answer (score 2):

1. It depends on your audience. Private members have a `-` prefix so you can recognize them as such. It is possible to suppress individual operations/attributes on class diagrams if desired.
2. Again, it depends on your audience. For brevity sake you can omit them if the context is clear.

Answer (score 1):

1-The Class diagram members (field and methods) do not depend on user interaction with class. It depends on the level of details. In General, Analysis class have not detailed information like private methods. Design class have detailed information about class including private methods. 
2- It depends on level of details or abstraction. From developer's view, It is good description.